# ScrollableTabRow Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

How can I display an Icon to the right of a ScrollableTabRow so the ScrollableTabRow scrolls using the space to the left of the icon?
By placing them in a Row the ScrollableTabRow appears to take up the entire horizontal space and the Icon is not displayed.

Would like something like this:
[image: Row of ScrollableTabRow & Icon]

Comment: If possible, add the code you wrote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could place your ScrollableTabRow and your Icon in a Row and give your ScrollableTabRow 'weight(1f)'. That way the icon stays in place and TabRow can be scrolled on the left of the icon.

```
 Row {
        ScrollableTabRow(
            selectedTabIndex = selectedTabIndex,
            contentColor = Color.White,
            edgePadding = 0.dp,
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
        ) {
            tabs.forEachIndexed { tabIndex, tab ->
                Tab(
                    selected = selectedTabIndex == tabIndex,
                    onClick = { onTabClick(tabIndex) },
                    text = { Text(text = tab) }
                )
            }
        }
        Icon(...)
    }
```